# How to display a loading screen after form.submit() in ember js

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

**Please consider:**
- a loading.hbs file exist, which gets called by ember when transaction occurs.
- Used `form.submit()` approach to retrieve data from the server in the Ember framework. I didn't use `this.store.findrecord()` because we faced some issue in downloading a file (created in the server) as an attachment and so went with the `form.submit()` approach.

**Objective:**
- a loading screen should get displayed when the `form.submit()` is triggered until we get the final data from the server.

**Problem:**
 - In ember, when we go for `this.store.findall()` approach, ember automatically search for a file like **loading.hbs** and it displays the file until the full data is downloaded from the server.
 - Since we are going via form.submit() approach, the ember is not searching for loading.hbs file to display.

Is there anyway, to display the loading.hbs file when the `form.submit()` is triggered.

Here is my code:

```
actions: {
    pdfClick(Id) {
      pdfId=document.getElementById("version_"+Id).value;
      let form = document.getElementById("pdfForm");
      form.action = Globals.urlPrefix + this.get('router.url') + "/" + Id; //This line creates the URL to be triggered
      form.submit();
      form.action = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a property and toggle it on/off before/after submit?You can then control when to display loading state there.

Answer (score 0):

All ya need is something like this:

component:

```
@action
submit() {
  this.set('loading', true);
  somePromise().then(() => this.set('loading', false));
}
```

template:

```
{{#if loading}}
  Please Wait
{{/if}}
```